# Catch specific URL pattern and do something in application scope bean

Tags: jsf

I have JSF web app project, I need to catch only incoming specific url pattern and do something in application scope bean. What is the best approach? I don't want to change existing functionality of webapp.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a filter that applies to an specific url pattern. And from the `doFilter` method call your application scoped bean.

Something like this:

```
@WebFilter("/yourpattern")
public class MyFilter extends HttpFilter {

    @Inject
    MyApplicationScopedBean myApplicationScopedBean;
    
    @Override
    protected void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) 
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        myApplicationScopedBean.doSomeThing();
        super.doFilter(request, response, chain);
    }
}
```